# Diferente resultado con 2 columnas con display grid o flex

Tags: html, css

Al usar un `display grid`, las columnas *renderizan* correctamente, al 50% del ancho, con `display flex`, hay una pequeña "desviación".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Por que se produce esto?

Suelo usar `flex` para maquetar dentro de otros elementos, este tipo de cosas no me da mucha confianza.

*Nota: probado en Chromium / Firefox*.

Código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding   : 0;
            margin    : 0;
        }

        .flex-cols {
            display       : flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            margin-top    : 1rem;
        }
        .grid-cols {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        }

        .col1 {
            background-color: orange;
        }
        .col2 {
            background-color: skyblue;
        }

        .text-content {
            background: grey;

            margin: 1rem auto;
            width : 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-cols">
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aliquam tempora minus sunt dolor asperiores eveniet, repellendus ad cupiditate molestias assumenda hic tenetur illum quidem sapiente vero. Tempore, quae illum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque aspernatur eligendi.s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-cols">
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aliquam tempora minus sunt dolor asperiores
                eveniet, repellendus ad cupiditate molestias assumenda hic tenetur illum quidem sapiente vero. Tempore, quae
                illum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse
                tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque
                aspernatur eligendi.s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La diferencia de entre ambos `display` radica en que `display: grid` se basa en un corsé de filas y columnas y `display: flex` se adapta naturalmente al contenido que tenga el contenedor.

**¿Esto que quiere decir?** Que al definir en con **grid** la propiedad `grid-template-columns: auto auto` estás diciendo al navegador que renderice la fila con dos columnas con el mismo tamaño cada una. En cambio con **flex** no estás definiendo ningún comportamiento para las columnas, por lo que el navegador le va a dar a cada una el tamaño con el que juzgue que su contenido va a poder visualizarse mejor (cuanto más ocupe el contenido de la columna mayor tamaño le va a dar a esta).

Si quieres hacer que con **flex** cada columna ocupe la mitad de su contenedor puedes usar en cada una de ellas la propiedad `flex: 1`. De esta manera estarás diciendo que quieres que cada columna ocupe la mitad de su contenedor.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding   : 0;
            margin    : 0;
        }

        .flex-cols {
            display       : flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            margin-top    : 1rem;
        }
        .grid-cols {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        }

        .col1 {
            background-color: orange;
            flex: 1;
        }
        .col2 {
            background-color: skyblue;
            flex: 1;
        }

        .text-content {
            background: grey;

            margin: 1rem auto;
            width : 80%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid-cols">
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aliquam tempora minus sunt dolor asperiores eveniet, repellendus ad cupiditate molestias assumenda hic tenetur illum quidem sapiente vero. Tempore, quae illum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque aspernatur eligendi.s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-cols">
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aliquam tempora minus sunt dolor asperiores
                eveniet, repellendus ad cupiditate molestias assumenda hic tenetur illum quidem sapiente vero. Tempore, quae
                illum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse
                tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque
                aspernatur eligendi.s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Agrega esto a tu código:**

```
.col1, .col2 {whith: 100%;}
```

o

```
.col1, .col2 {whith: 50%;}
```

Después de esto notarás que con **display grid** los contenedores no tendrán el mismo tamaño, pero los **flex** si, logicamente no vas a usar ambos asi que para cada uso, cada fórmula.

```css
        * {
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding   : 0;
            margin    : 0;
        }

        .flex-cols {
            display       : flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            margin-top    : 1rem;
        }
        .grid-cols {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        }

        .col1 {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: orange;
        }
        .col2 {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: skyblue;
        }

        .text-content {
            background: grey;

            margin: 1rem auto;
            width : 80%;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="grid-cols">
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aliquam tempora minus sunt dolor asperiores eveniet, repellendus ad cupiditate molestias assumenda hic tenetur illum quidem sapiente vero. Tempore, quae illum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque aspernatur eligendi.s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-cols">
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cumque aliquam tempora minus sunt dolor asperiores
                eveniet, repellendus ad cupiditate molestias assumenda hic tenetur illum quidem sapiente vero. Tempore, quae
                illum.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col2">
            <div class="text-content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Cum, ipsa! Explicabo ullam voluptatem, esse
                tempore, officiis ratione velit laborum soluta deleniti dignissimos eum sapiente id quis modi eaque
                aspernatur eligendi.s
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```